# JDK on RHEL on IBM Power Series

Tags: java-6, rhel5

We are looking for  JDK 1.6 on for RHEL 5.5 on IBM Power Series. Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137561.html

go to the very bottom

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the link, however there is nothing on Power Series, they are for X64.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html#java6

I know this is super old, but happened to see while searching for something else and figured I'd answer in case anyone else wanted to know.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know ubuntu is shipping it as part of Canonical repository.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ppc64el/ThirdParty#IBM_Java

Answer (score 0):

All the IBM Java's downloads for RHEL are kept here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html